# nuxt.config.ts won't read env variables

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I find myself in a rather strange situation where my nuxt.config.ts configuration doesn't recognize my overrided variables with NUXT_ on an .env file on SSR mode:

```
runtimeConfig: {
        strapiAdminToken: '',
        public: {
            strapiBaseUri: '',
            stripe: {
                publishableKey: '',
            },
        }
    }
```

.env file example:

```
NUXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_BASE_URI=blablabla
NUXT_STRAPI_ADMIN_TOKEN=blababla
```

My application run with a docker-compose:

```
nuxt-app:
    container_name: nuxt-app
    image: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/nuxt-app:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./.env/:/src/.env
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - Strapi
```

Comment: Have you try `console.log(useRuntimeConfig())` to dump all the configs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT:

Based on the new context you've provided, try doing this.

Docker set's it's own environment, and exposes all the variables you set in your compose file.

```yaml
nuxt-app:
    container_name: nuxt-app
    image: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/nuxt-app:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./.env/:/src/.env
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - Strapi
    environment:
      NUXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_BASE_URI: "blablabla"
```

```js
runtimeConfig: {
    strapiAdminToken: '',
    public: {
        strapiBaseUri: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_BASE_URI,
        stripe: {
            publishableKey: '',
        },
    },
}
```

### [Nuxt3 .env](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/env)

> Nuxt CLI has built-in dotenv support in development mode and when running nuxi build and nuxi generate.
>
> In addition to any process environment variables, if you have a .env file in your project root directory, it will be automatically loaded at dev, build and generate time. Any environment variables set there will be accessible within your nuxt.config file and modules.

What does your `.env` file look like?  Does it match the standard format of `<KEY>=<VALUE>`?   Where is it located? It should be at the root of project.

If you're using a Dockerized container, make sure you set the `envs` in your `develeopment.yaml` file.

Comment: Is there no way on Nuxt to read unread environment variables on buildtime at runtime?

Comment: Can you please add more context to this?   What does your .env file look like? Nuxt will read your .env file at runtime, and pull in the values you have stored there.    You can also set static values in your `nuxt.config` file if you aren't using a .env file.

I don't understand what you're trying to do, or what's failing.

Comment: OK so to add more context: On SSR mode, Nuxt will take all environment variables (.env file included) and compiles it with all the rest. .env file will get ignored at runtime. For counter that, I define variables on the nuxt.config.ts that I override with environment variables that begin with NUXT_ as mentioned on the official documentation. My env file is composed of key pair values (ex: NUXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_BASE_URI=blablabla). BUT actually my nuxt application don't recognize theses variables

Comment: Thank you for adding more context to this!    I've just updated my answer, please take a look and try that.